# Book Suggestion - Complex algebraic surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, coherent-sheaves

I am studying for an exam of algebraic geometry, in particular, I am dealing with ruled surfaces and numerical invariants, rational surfaces, Castelnuovo's Theorem and its application.
I am reading the Beauville's book "Complex Algebraic Surfaces", but I realised that I need some introductory books first. 
I need a book that could help me understand Cech cohomology as an instrument. Moreover I'm finding difficult to understand the concept of exact sequences of sheaves, their application (e.g. in the proof of Noether Enriques theorem) and their relation to divisors. 
Without these notion I cannot understand the proof of Castelnuovo contractibility criterion, the Noether Enriques theorem and another theorem concerning minimal surfaces, which are some of the main theorems of the exam.
My basis knoledge is the Rick Miranda Book, which I sudied deeply.
The Shafarevich and Hartshorne books are not helping me. 
Some suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest you try the standard references (Shafarevich, Hartshorne, Eisenbud & Harris, Vakil, Goertz & Wedhorn, Perrin, Huybrechts, etc.) and when you are genuinely stuck, ask your mathematical question here on MSE. But since your background is analytic, maybe you will like Huybrechts book "Complex Geometry" more than the other books.

Comment: I agree with Andrew: in particular, when I was learning this stuff, I did find Shafarevich genuinely helpful. Having said that, if you really can't get on with that book, you could try looking in Griffiths & Harris, _Principles of Algebraic Geometry_: it has both the foundational material on sheaves, cohomology, and line bundles, as well as applications to surfaces --- in particular, the kind of theorems you mention. But care should be taken: the book can be difficult to digest, the treatment is very analytic, and it is notorious for typos. Good luck!